# Displaying linked database results in single HTML table

Tags: python, django, django-templates, html-table

I have several database tables that are linked by foreign keys (you'll have to forgive the basic examples here, I'm having trouble copy/pasting out of my development env right now).

```
# models.py
class Task(models.Model):
    details = models.ForeignKey(Details)
    task = models.CharField(max_length=1024, null=false)

class Activity(models.Model):
    task = models.ForeignKey(Task)
    activity = models.CharField(max_length=1024)

class Resources(models.Model):
    activity = models.ForeignKey(Activity, null=false)
    resources = models.CharField (max_length=1024)
```

I need to display these results in a single table.  Note that a Task can have no  Activities and an Activity might not have any Resources, etc.  For example:

- Task1

  - Activity1

    - Resource1
    - Resource2
  - Activity2
- Task2

  - ...etc...

So far I have created a table in my forms.py that contains ALL of the fields that could possibly be present in a database result.  So:

```
# forms.py
class ViewTable(tables.Table):
    task = tables.Column(default=' ')
    activity = tables.Column(default=' ')
    resource = tables.Column(default=' ')
```

I was then using `itertools.chain` to link the results together in the correct order and then render them into the template.  I am at a dead-end here:

```
# views.py
table = None
for task in tasks:
    if table:
        table = list(chain(table, task)
    else:
        table = task

    for activity in Activities.objects.filter(tasks=task):
        table = list(chain(table, activity))
        for resource in Resources.objects.filter(activity=activity):
            table = list(chain(table, resource))

return render(request, 'table.html', {'table', table, })


# table.html
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Tasks</th>
        <th>Activity</th>
        <th>Resources</th>
    </tr>
{% for item in table %}
    <tr>
        <th>{{ item.task }}</th>
        <th>{{ item.activity }}</th>
        <th>{{ item.resource }}</th>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

This doesn't work because if I only have one task (and no activities or resources) then the object isn't iterable, so I get an error when I try to render it in the template.

But overall, I feel like this is a sloppy and slow way of doing things, and I'm having trouble coming up with a better way.  Fixes or completely alternate recommendations are welcome!

The overall goal is to get something that displays like this:

```
Tasks     Activities     Resources
-------------------------------------
task1
           activity1
                         resource1
                         resource2
           activity2
task2
```

Comment: Not sure why you would use django-tables2 in this case, it also seems you do not use it at all in you view code.
Apart from that: if you get an error that something is not iterable, you should check if it is before trying to iterate over it.

Comment: You're right, i didn't realize that `tables.Table` was a part of `django-tables2`.  So that part isn't necessary.  My question was how to come up with something like I posted in my "overall goal".  Whether that object is iterable (fixing the code that I have) or a completely different solution, i'm all ears.

Comment: Hmm, looking into your examples, there are multiple syntax errors (`false` vs `False`, missing parenthesis). Please read how to provide a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) No need to provide a complete django project, but your code should run without syntax errors, view should be complete, and your models without external dependencies...

Comment: Futhermore, if you have a hard time building things with itertools chain, it might be wise to try to make a naive list implementation first. It might not be fast enough for your application, but it should give you insight in the problem before optimizing.

Comment: You're right, I had to write it all out by hand without syntax highlighting because (as I noted) my VM isn't working with C&P right now.  It seems that the difference between `false` and `False` is distracting you from my actual question, so I will just move on.  Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't realize that I could iterate through an object and add each of those items to a list.  I was able to solve my own problem like so:

```
all = []

task = Tasks.objects.get(id=1)
all.append(task)

activities = Activities.objects.filter(task_id=task)
for activity in activities:
    all.append(activity)
    resources = Resources.objects.filter(activity_id=activity)
    for resource in resources:
        all.append(resource)
```

From there i'm able to just drop `all` into my template and access `{{ all.activity_num }}`, etc.

I guess I need to do some more reading about how objects are constructed.  Thanks!